# Why deconfiguring interfaces is a need on reboot?

Tags: raspbian, network-interface, reboot

When I reboot the Raspbian (Debian 7.8) it waits around 10 seconds before shutdown at "deconfiguring network interfaces" step. What would be if we make the system skip this step? Why is deconfiguring network interfaces needed anyway?